# PHP with mysql SELECT LIMIT

Tags: php, mysql, select, prestashop, limit

I have a request (mysql) in PHP who gives me many results and it works like a charm. Here is an example of a request who gives me 115 results :

```
public static function getInfo($start, $limit) {
 $sql = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->ExecuteS(
  SELECT blablabla FROM blabla ORDER BY bla LIMIT $start,$limit
 );
 return $sql;
}
```

In my php file, i've got :

```
$rq = getInfo (0, 0);
$count_rq = (int)count($rq);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count_rq; ++$i) {
 .... do my things ....
}
```

Here is the problem : in this configuration, it shows only results 1 to 42...

When i do some modifications/tests, it shows strange results :

```
Modification => for ($i = 42; $i < $count_rq; ++$i) {.......}
I got 0 result.

Modification => for ($i = 43; $i < $count_rq; ++$i) {.......}
I got results 43 from 115 !..

Modification => for ($i = 60; $i < $count_rq; ++$i) {.......}
I got results 60 from 115 !..
```

I've tried to modify the "LIMIT" but i don't understand. Here is the result when i do modifications/test :

```
(i'm using for ($i = 0; $i < $count_rq; ++$i) {.......})
 Modification => $rq = getInfo (0, 20);
     I got results 1 to 20.
 Modification => $rq = getInfo (0, 50);
     I got results 1 to 42.
 Modification => $rq = getInfo (10, 0);
     I got results 1 to 42.
 Modification => $rq = getInfo (10, 30);
     I got results 11 to 40.
```

I don't know how I can show all of my results? I want to have a code who can show 115 results when request got 115 results, or 10 results when request got 10 results. How can I do that? Why am I limited to first 42 results?

Comment: What exactly does this method `Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->ExecuteS`? Does it execute the query *and* fetch all rows?

Comment: Thanks for reply Charlotte.
I guess because It's from prestashop : "ExecuteS" execute the query and get back all results into multidimensional array..

Comment: What do you see if you do `var_dump($rq);`?

Comment: it shows the entire request (115 results).

Comment: Are they regularily indexed from 0 to 114?

Comment: Yes it shows every data from 0 to 114...

Comment: Have you tried a `foreach` statement?

Comment: What are you doing in for block? Can we see the code?

Comment: I guess @TheDrot has catched the problem :D

Comment: It is most likely something to do with the action you are performing on the items in the loop. Looks like something about row #42 makes your code break out of the loop. Either post your full code or replace it with simple "print" for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You use limit in your request and check that MySQL SELECT is retrieving good results.
- Then, why do you start `for` loop in any other thing than `0`??
- If your request is getting 115 rows you should use this sentence to iterate through all of them:

  for ($i = 0; $i < $count_rq; ++$i)

Good luck.